Trilogy that was downloaded on a Nook back in 2010 ish
The trilogy is about a boy who was trapped in a video game that his mom bought for him. During this trilogy, he becomes magically stuck inside the game and finds out a girl from his same high school is also stuck in the game. They befriend a Roman legionnaire named (Markus?) and are attempting to beat the final level to escape the game.
The conclusion is the two waking up in hospital beds where they find out each time they lost a life in the game, they flatlined in real life.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the names of any other characters or names of places they visited?  What was the theme/style of the game?  (e.g. Are we talking about an MMO or a single-player RPG?)
